# How can we prevent the upper floor in a split-level home from getting too warm?

Tags: hvac, heating, central-heating

I have a split level home.  Main floor contains living dining and kitchen.  8 stairs up to top level with 3 bedrooms and a bathroom.  Down 6 steps from main level to family room and from there down another 6 steps to fully underground sub-basement.

My last house was a ranch which we liked to keep warm at about 75F or so in the winter.  With the thermostat set to 75 in the current split level, the top level must be 90F if not higher.  The thermostat is in the dining room next to a sizable window.  I just covered the supply vents in the top level but I'm not sure if this is safe/efficient/productive, etc.  The bottom 2 levels have electric floor heating in addition to vents from furnace.  Furnace is in sub-basement.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Usually we have dampers to adjust multi level homes in winter pushing more heat down stairs and less upstairs, if there are no main trunk dampers individual room vents usually have dampers or are adjustable. I never recommend totally closing a duct off because I have seen ducts split and flex line blow off when vents were closed too much. Opening the lower vents and partially closing the upper vents will help.

I have also found that keeping the main fan running in low can also help as the air is moved constantly so the upstairs won't have the heat naturally moving up.

Comment: Both suggestions are key--flow adjustment and plenty of circulation. I have a four-level home and a harsh climate and this isn't really an issue.

Comment: Short of new ductwork,  Would moving the thermostat to the upstairs location that you want to control  be an option since there is a supplemental heat source for the downstairs. ??  If the furnace is due for replacement it might be time to think about a multi zone set up with a thermostat for each zone.

Comment: @alaska man, good question but Just moving a thermostat will cause the opposite problem, cold on the lower floor. Duct work won’t need to be changed. if the registers are fixed they need to be replaced but that is not that expensive expensive. A cheap  option I used on a couple of flips we actually used metal foil tape to reduce a few fixed registers , cover some of the area from the back. Verify flow and adjust as needed. Aluminum foil could be used if you press the foil into the register so it will hold until a replacement register can be installed.